# icon & iconCls in ExtJS

Tags: plugins, extjs, icons, extjs4, config

1-Why some component just have 'iconCls' config and do not have 'icon' config? (for example Window just have iconCls).
 2- Is there any plugin for makeing icon managment more easily for Ext 4, like 
 Ext.ux.TDGi.iconMgr in Ext 3.
 Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iconCls is the preferred way to add an icon to things. Why some have both and some only have one, framework inconstancies. Ext JS 4 should be better with this.

Comment: Why is iconCls the preferred way?

Comment: @Mark It's much better to maintain CSS files for this than to maintain urls to images somewhere in your javascript.